# Two integer prisms

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Two rectangular prisms have the same height, but one is 38 times bigger than the other. They all have integer edge lengths and the diagonals on their faces also have integer lengths. What is the height, the length and the width of the bigger prism, knowing that it’s the smallest possible?

Comment: Vf gur fznyyrfg rqtr bs gur ynetre erpgnathyne cevfz terngre guna svir uhaqerq gjragl rvtug?

Comment: 38 times bigger is ambiguous. Do you mean in volume?  Also - *"They all have integer edge lengths"*, Do you mean they *"both  have integer edge lengths"*?

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica You’re right.

Comment: @Displaymaths hey can you please reply to my previous comment as well... its rot 13(Vf gur fznyyrfg rqtr bs gur ynetre erpgnathyne cevfz terngre guna svir uhaqerq gjragl rvtug?)

Comment: @Ankit ? I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Displaymaths rot13 stands (roughly) for “rotate 13 places”. If a=1, b=2, etc, rot13(a) is 1+13=14=n, so rot13(abc)=nop. You can google “rot13“ for online decoders.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, and coded correctly, then the answer is

> height $1155$, width and depth are $1008, 1100$ for the smaller one and $6300, 6688$ for the larger one.

I simply

> searched for every $h$, list out all the possible sizes and check whether there is one that is $38$ times larger than (which I interpret as multiply by a factor of $38$, not $39$) another.
>
>
>  I searched for all $h \leq 10^5$ to verify that it is indeed the smallest one.

Comment: Nice, however I wanted someone to solve with number theory.

Comment: @Displaymaths That's what the [no-computers] tag is for.